# Subscribing to Multiple Topics in JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, storage, distributed-computing

I am working on a distributed storage project. I am implemented it using Java EE. In my storage objects are replicated at multiple servers and in case of any update at a server, i need to propagate the same to other replicas.

What is the best way to implement the same?

Currently i am thinking of using JMS pub/sub to make my communication asynchronous. But since each server is responsible for multiple objects i need to subscribe it with multiple topics (that can be changes dynamically).

Please let me know if its possible in JMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use JMS destination wildcards. As I know, most JMS compatible products like Apache ActiveMQ, Tibco EMS support such feature.

The usage in ActiveMQ:
http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html.